# Using a macro inside a \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion

I am facing some - probably very silly - problem. I want a multi-version document - one for me, one for my students and one complete version.

The idea is that you just change the versioning in the beginning of the document and it switches the font's color for the parts I want to leave blank (usually my examples) : on the student version it writes parts of the text in the same color as the background (thus invisible), on teacher's version, it writes in a different color (so that I know what my students have to fulfill) and the complete version writes everything in black. I have a big document and the system works really well.

But I'm just struggling a bit when it comes to handling this system with tikz. The following code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\fondExercice{gray!10}
\def\couleurMaitre{gray!80}
\def\couleurComplet{black}

\newcommand{\versionEleve}{
    \def\macouleur{\fondExercice}
    \def\edition{E}
}
\newcommand{\versionMaitre}{
    \def\macouleur{\couleurMaitre}
    \def\edition{P}
}
\newcommand{\versionComplete}{
    \def\macouleur{\couleurComplet}
    \def\edition{C}
}

\newcommand\couleurTik[1][black]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\edition}{E}}{\fondExercice}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \versionEleve

    The current color is \couleurTik[yellow]

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[\couleurTik] (0,0) circle (1);    
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

doesn't work and produces an error I don't understand : `\couleurTik[yellow]` produces the expected result but `\draw[\couleurTik] (0,0) circle (1);` produces the mistake.

I guess it's some kind of expansion problem, but altough I tried to read a bit about that, it remains quite mysterious to me.

Anybody has a clue on why it fails ? Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :**

After looking for `colorlet`, I found out that this works

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\fondExercice{gray!10}
\def\couleurMaitre{gray!80}
\def\couleurComplet{black}

\newcommand{\versionEleve}{
    \def\macouleur{\fondExercice}
    \colorlet{couleurTik}{\fondExercice}
    \def\edition{E}
}
\newcommand{\versionMaitre}{
    \def\macouleur{\couleurMaitre}
    \colorlet{couleurTik}{\couleurMaitre}
    \def\edition{P}
}
\newcommand{\versionComplete}{
    \def\macouleur{\couleurComplet}
    \colorlet{couleurTik}{\couleurComplet}
    \def\edition{C}
}


\begin{document}
    \versionEleve


    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[color=couleurTik] (0,0) circle (1);   
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

But I still don't get why the first code didn't ...

Comment: You could just redefine the styles. But I am afraid that some student will just use `pdftotext` or something like this to find out what you tried to hide. ;-)

Comment: They just get a printed version of the document, so they cannot do that. But the problem is not there for me, I am quite happy with this system, it's just with tikz that it's not working.

Comment: What I meant is that you may want to define a style `couleurTik` instead of the macro `couleurTik` and set it accordingly to white (?) or something visible.

Comment: Why not using `\definecolor` and `\colorlet`?

Comment: Is it required to use `\definecolor`here ? `\draw[gray!10]`works and my macro produces gray!10, that's the thing I don't understand.

Comment: The problem is most likely with expansion, i.e., the moment the `if` is evaluated. TikZ expects a color name as argument of `draw`, and if you provide a complex expression with `ifthenelse` then it fails, because although it will finally evaluate into a color name the expression itself is not a color name. This kind of complex macros as arguments is usually better avoided, although simple macros can be used (e.g., in the original example you can use `\draw[\fondExercice]`).

Comment: Thanks Marijn. So that I know why it failed for the next time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define a new `tikzstyle` for each version using the defined colours.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\fondExercice{gray!10}
\def\couleurMaitre{gray!80}
\def\couleurComplet{black}

\newcommand{\versionEleve}{
    \def\macouleur{\fondExercice}
    \def\edition{E}
    \tikzstyle{mycolor} = [\macouleur]
}
\newcommand{\versionMaitre}{
    \def\macouleur{\couleurMaitre}
    \def\edition{P}
    \tikzstyle{mycolor} = [\macouleur]
}
\newcommand{\versionComplete}{
    \def\macouleur{\couleurComplet}
    \def\edition{C}
    \tikzstyle{mycolor} = [\macouleur]
}

\newcommand\couleurTik[1][black]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\edition}{E}}{\fondExercice}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \versionEleve
    %\versionMaitre
    %\versionComplete

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[mycolor] (0,0) circle (1);    
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzstyle` has been deprecated for several years.